# Coldfusion Lucee 4.5.2.018 (Linux) - REST service (can't cast String) JSON

Tags: mysql, web-services, coldfusion, railo, lucee

working on REST web-service, i don't have much experience coldfusion web-services.It is very basic web-service.Please if you guys can point me, what im doing wrong. it will be great help.

Application Server : Lucee 4.5.2.018 (Linux)

Please find below my code.

Component-Function/ Web-Service.

`<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/hello">`

```
    <cffunction name="formPost" access="remote" returnType="struct" httpMethod="POST" restPath="/name" hint="POST Method" produces="application/json">
           <cfargument name="firstname" type="String" restArgSource="Form">
           <cfargument name="lastname" type="String" restArgSource="Form">
         <cfset myStruct =  structnew()>  
           <cfset myStruct.FirstName = firstname>
           <cfset myStruct.LastName  = lastname>

            <cfquery name="Qry" datasource="myDSN">
                select col1,col2 from myTableData
            </cfquery>
           <cfset myJsonVar = serializeJSON(Qry) />
           <cfreturn myJsonVar>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Calling web-service

```
<cfhttp url="http://mydev:8888/rest/Example/hello/name" method="POST"  result="res"  port="8888" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="firstname" value="Dan">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="lastname" value="Gates">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#res#">
```

Problem:
When defining `returnType="struct"` Error `string   can't cast String [{"COLUMNS":["COL1","COL2"],"DATA":[["0","7777777"],["0","888888"]]}] to a value of type [struct]`

When defining `returnType="string"` No error coming `"{\"COLUMNS\":[\"COL1\",\"COL2\"],\"DATA\":[[\"0\",\"7777777\"],[\"0\",\"888888\"]]}"`

Trying get [DATA] values in loop

`<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(d.DATA)#" index="i">
        <cfloop from="1" to=#ArrayLen(d.DATA[i])# index="j">
              <cfset resultSrt =d.COLUMNS[j]&" = " &d.DATA[i][j]>
              #resultSrt#<br>
        </cfloop>
   </cfloop>`

Message: `No matching property [DATA] found in [string]`
Stacktrace:`The Error Occurred in
/opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/calling.cfm: line 52 
50: 
51: 
52: <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(d.DATA)#" index="i">
53: <cfloop from="1" to=#ArrayLen(d.DATA[i])# index="j">
54: <cfset resultSrt =d.COLUMNS[j]&" = " &d.DATA[i][j]>`
[image: Output]

Comment: Aren't you serializing an object as a JSON string?  If so, the ReturnType should be "string".  You could also set the ReturnType to "JSON" and not use the SerializeJSON function.  Depending on the version of CF, you may want to also consider using JSONUtil https://github.com/CFCommunity/jsonutil

Comment: im just doing serializeJSON() does it return string ? im not casting anywhere. i also tried return time JSON  didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all since you are returning a query, you should set `returnType` to `Query`.

If you have set `produces` attribute of `cffunction` to `application/json`, in that case you don't need to perform explicit JSON serialization while returning data. ColdFusion will automatically do it for you. You can just write:

```
<cfreturn Qry />
```

To read the result returned from the service you need to deserialize the data. Like this:

```
<cfdump var="#deserializeJson(res.filecontent)#">
```

Comment: Thanks for response i did as you said still giving me string output.  let me clear one think when running same code in CF10 app server it is working find it is giving me return array

Comment: *i did as you said still giving me string output* I modified your code exactly as Pankaj described and it worked perfectly with Lucee.  I suspect you forgot to refresh, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Leigh i just uploaded my output its showing string. i want DATA... how can i do separate data? should i use find() function to pick my required  value ?

Comment: *my output its showing string* The output is still wrong. When you see the quotes being escaped with a \, like this   `{\"COLUMNS\":...`, it typically means you are mistakenly encoding the result twice.  Something is different your code. If you apply the steps Pankaj suggested - carefully (one at a time), it will work.  1) set returnType to Query. 2) Remove the serializeJSON and just return `Qry`. *Refresh the web service if needed*  3) Deserialize the response string `deserializeJson(res.filecontent)`